# How to type nextjs endpoint with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios, prisma, react-query

Is there a way to type a nextjs endpoint, so when sending a request I directly know the returned type?

**Example Endpoint**

```
const getHandler = async (
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse,
    prisma: PrismaClient
) => {
    // query data and type it somehow?
}
```

**Example Query**

```
const {data: myData} = useQuery(["myKey"], () => axios.get("/api/myEndpoint"))
```

No matter what I try, the type of myData is always `AxiosResponse<any, any> | undefined`

I know that I just can create an interface and type type response again, but is there any other way? I appreciate every advice, thanks in advance!

Comment: That's what tRPC tries to do. it is perfect for such a use case. however for small projects in app router, you can write your nodejs code directly in the server components. So it would be type-safe. but for bigger projects, where you need more advanced and cleaner backend code, you can use tTRPC (https://trpc.io/)